# Entire even function with exponential type which strictly decreases and vanishes at infinities

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking for the function $f$ which satisfies the following conditions:

1. $f$ should be an even entire function, i.e. $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(z)=f(-z)$.
2. $f$ should have a real value in both real and imaginary axis, i.e. $f(\mathbb{R}\cup i\mathbb{R})\subset \mathbb{R}$.
3. $f$ should monotonically decrease on real axis as $|x|\rightarrow 0$: in other words, $f'(x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus {0})\neq 0$.
4. $f(0)>0$ and $f$ should vanish on the infinity on real axis, i.e. $\lim_{x\in \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \infty }f(x)=0$.
5. $f$ should be an exponential type, i.e. $|f(z)|\leq A e^{c|z|}$ on large enough $|z|$ for some $A,c$.

The motivation of this question is to find the entire function with exponential type whose shape is similar with the Gaussian function $e^{-x^2}$. We can easilly see that gaussian function satisfies all the conditions except condition 5.

Another example I have tried is $J_0(z)$ or $\sin x/x$, which satisfies every conditions but condition 3 and 4. There are various examples which satisfies all the properties above but condition 1., for example, $(1/1+z^2)$.

Maybe such function $f$ exists but not in the closed form, for example, in the form of Taylor expansion: if so, then I want its rough form. Maybe such function never exists due to the property of exponential type functions: if so, then I want a rough proof of it.

Comment: How about $e^{-z^2}$ ?

Comment: @Salcio Substituting $z$ into $iz$ gives $e^{z^2}$, which is larger than $e^z$ always when $z$ is real.

Comment: With $z=re^{i\varphi}$ is $f(z)=e^{-re^{2i\varphi}}$ holomorphic? (Trying to mash $e^-z$ and $e^{-z^2}$ to fullfill all your criteria)

Comment: @quarague Seems not: it violates the polar version of Cauchy-Riemann eq. $\partial f/\partial r = \partial f/ir\partial \varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I myself showed the non-existence of such function. [Edit-Thanks to @conrad, Taking $a=0$ does not directly means that the function is exponential-type zero, showing that the argument below is flawed.]

Since $f$ is an entire exponential-type function, we may write

$$
f(z)=z^m e^{az+b} \prod_i (1-z_i/a_i)
$$

By scaling let $f(0)=1$. Then, with the fact that $f$ is even, $a=b=m=0$. This implies that

$$
f(z)=\prod_i (1-z_i/a_i)
$$
which now shows that $f$ is an exponential-type zero function. Now since [Bernstein Inequality](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X09004478) shows, for an exponential-type $\tau$ function, if $f$ is bounded on the real axis,

$$
|f'(x)|\leq \tau |f(x)|,\quad x\in \mathbb{R}
$$

but since $\tau=0$, $|f'(x)|=0$, showing $f=0$.

Comment: why do you claim $f$ is exponential type zero? $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is of the kind above as is $\cos z$ for example (in other words they do not have a nontrivial $e^{az+b}$ factor and are even with $f(0)=1$); you never use condition 3 in your contradiction and without that  $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ works as it satisfies all but 3

Comment: @Conrad You are right. I just misconsidered that taking $a=0$ directly leads to the exponential-type zero. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: you should try and do a search on the site and see if this problem hasn't been solved before as it seems familiar somehow;

Comment: @Conrad I've tried to search some, but didn't found. Please let me know if there are some related questions.